# delete not working to filter response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on a service which uses restify and mongoose as odm. Below is the service response which I get after DB call.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5a548b7c025cfcffdd286e0f",
        "createdAt": "2018-01-09T09:29:32.515Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-01-09T10:59:49.159Z",
        "subject": "Hello buddy.",
        "body": "i am good and fine.",
        "category": "email service",
        "category_id": "232",
        "author": "5a5485834c2274ce5d5e54f8",
        "__v": 0,
        "images": [
            "https://google.com"
        ],
        "email content": [
            {
                "_id": "5a549dcb80a16b2e822357ae",
                "createdAt": "2018-01-09T10:47:39.883Z",
                "updatedAt": "2018-01-09T10:47:39.883Z",
                "body": "my first comment",
                "name": "asdf"
                "password":"312312"
                "__v": 0,
                "photos": []
            }
        ]
}]
```

Below is the code I wrote. But it is not deleting the property in the response.

```
Posts.find({_id: catId}).populate('author')
.exec(function(err, list) {
  if(err) {
    return next(new errors.InvalidContentError(err.errors.name.message),);};
    res.send(200, massageResponse(list, createResponse));
    next();
  });
});
let createResponse = function (list) {
  const trimmedList = list.map((element) => {
    delete element.createdAt;
      return element;
  });
  return trimmedList;
}
let massageResponse = function (list, callback) {
  return callback(list);
}
```

Comment: Check the JavaScript console for syntax errors. Your code as posted won't run at all because of the syntax error in the `return next...` line. Also make sure the curly braces match up as you expect. And note that code after a `return` statement doesn't get run at all.

Comment: that was a typo. I donot understand why the delete element.createdAt is not working but element.createdAt = undefined is working perfectly fine. anybody has an answer to this?

Comment: This works fine, can't reproduce the problem.